# How to connect to Neo4j server running on Windows machine from Ubuntu machine?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, neo4j, graph-databases

I am using Neo4j graph database. Its running on Windows PC at url: `http://localhost:7474/browser/`. Now I want to get access to this server from machine running Ubuntu OS, so that I can access Neo4j browser and can use it for development purpose as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need to do: -

1. Uncomment "org.neo4j.server.webserver.address" and provide a valid IP-Address on which you want to bind your neo4j http service at port 7474 in your neo4j-server.properties and restart your neo4j server.
2. Try accessing you Neo4j server on local machine by entering URL - http://:7474/ (Do not use localhost).
3. Switch off all firewalls and ensure :7474 is accessible from any remote machine. You may test it with Telnet too.

In case all the above works then you are done and your Neo4j server is accessible from remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to configure your `conf/neo4j-server.properties` file to allow access from non-localhost addresses.  Here's the relevant part of my file:

```
# Let the webserver only listen on the specified IP. Default is localhost (only
# accept local connections). Uncomment to allow any connection. Please see the
# security section in the neo4j manual before modifying this.
#org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Ok. I uncommented this line: #org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0 But still I am not able to access it from Ubuntu. Do we need to configure something on Ubuntu system as well?

Comment: Did you restart Neo4j?

Comment: Do you know if you need to open up the port 7474 in Windows?  Perhaps the system firewall or one you have installed?  Also have a look through http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/security-server.html